# The Amplitude of the Correlation Function Peaks After Matched Filtering

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, autocorrelation

I have 2 signals: $s_1(t)$ and $s_2(t)$. The autocorrelation functions are given by $R_{s_1}(\tau)$ and $R_{s_2}(\tau)$ with $|R_{s_2}(\tau)|<|R_{s_1}(\tau)|$.

I would like to know if the previous inequality remains true after transmission in an identical channel for the 2 signals, i.e: $r_1(t)=s_1(t)\ast h(t)+n(t)$ and $r_2(t)=s_2(t)\ast h(t)+n(t)$. Do we have $|R_{r_2}(\tau)|<|R_{r_1}(\tau)|$. And if it's true how to prove it?

Comment: Do we have some info about $ h $?

Comment: Could you please review my answer?

Comment: Where is the **matched** filtering that is mentioned in the _title_ of the question? The text of your question refers to transmission of the signals through identical channels, but _no_ filtering of any kind is being done at the receiver. And $h(t)$ _cannot_ be the matched filter for _both_ signals unless the only difference between the two signals is that $s_2 = \alpha s_1$ where $|\alpha|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Without any restrictions on $ h $ you may build some very non real world cases.
Especially if we're talking about the correlation function without the removal of the DC component.

For instance, think of the case of $ {s}_{2} \left( t \right) $ is a gaussian function with its peak equals to 1.5. Now, $ {s}_{1} \left( t \right) $ to be a gaussian with a peak of 1 but with a DC of 2.

Make $ h $ to be an High Pass Filter and you get that their auto correlation won't obey the proposition in your question.

Comment: @user62523 Did Royi properly answer you question? If so, please mark this off as correct to close this question out, or otherwise clarify what else you want him to clear up. Thank you!